# AWS - How to connect to a specific port using Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I have multiple Node.js servers running on an **Amazon Web Service** application. One of the servers is being ran on port 8080. How do I connect to this port?

Using `var socket = io.connect('example.region-1.elasticbeanstalk.com')` connects me to the primary server. What I need is something like `var socket = io.connect('example.region-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:8080')`.

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: I get a `WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.region-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:2000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established` error

Comment: Works fine when I run the servers locally. Perhaps it's some kind of a blocked port issue with AWS?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. If you are running something on an ec2 server, ports are blocked by default.

Comment: I will look into this now, thank you. Also, is there a way to connect users within the server to a parallel server without opening ports?

Comment: I opened ports 2000-2100, still same issue

Comment: any succus on this ? because i already spend 3 days but no positive response :(